# How can I use fontawesome with material bootstrap5 in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I installed material bootstrap5 to my Vue project and its working fine. I can use components and icons directly from material bootstrap page like :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-floating insta" style="background-color: #ac2bac;" href="#!" role="button">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-floating facebook" style="background-color: #ac2bac;" href="#!" role="button">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

and i get nice icons; but i want to use fontawseome icons and when i paste the icon code from fontawesome site for vuejs like

```
<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-paper-plane" />
```

It doesn't work and it shows nothing. I installed font awesome with mdb5. How can I use it ?

the whole code is:

```
 <div class="SocialMediaBar">
<div class="socialMediaIcons" >
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-floating insta" style="background-color: #ac2bac;" href="#!" role="button">
  <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-floating facebook" style="background-color: #ac2bac;" href="#!" role="button">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
</div>
```

It show 2 icons from mdb5 site and nothing more.

Comment: Why not using `<i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i>` if this is how your project is configured?

Comment: what you see on the site is wrong, it should be `<font-awesome-icon icon="paper-plane" />`, if you want fas, far, fab etc, you use `:icon="['far', 'paper-plane']"`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone never understood why it's so hard to get FA to just work.